# How do I make a button read text and do a specific function

Tags: java

```
public class Main extends JFrame{

    public JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();

    public JButton run = new JButton("Run Code");

    public Main(){
        setSize(800, 600);
        setTitle("SPL Editor");
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add(ta);
        add(run, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        run.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String input = ta.getText();

                if (input == "createWindow;"){
                    JFrame f = new JFrame("Made with the SPL Language");

                    f.setVisible(true);
                    f.setSize(800, 600);
                    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Main();
    }
}
```

> Im trying to make that line in the TextArea open a window but it wont work, ive >been working on a programming language and I need help. So basically its >saying, if the input is "createWindow;" then a window should open but it does >nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `input.equals("createWindow;")` instead of `input == "createWindow;"` in that last if statement.

When checking strings for equality, using `==` will cause Java to  see if the objects are in the same memory location, and will usually not work. `.equals()` is a method built into the `String` class that works for most people's intentions, so I would advise you to always use `.equals()` when checking equality for Strings.

In short, `.equals()` will check to see if the contents of the String are equal,
`==` will check to see if the memory references to the objects are equal.

Comment: No problem, be sure to accept an answer if it solved your issue, and good luck with your project!